# Eclipse. Move a static final variable to a static nested class

Tags: eclipse, static, refactoring, move

How to do that? I have got the static variable in the class called `Constants`. Now I'd like to move it to the static nested class called `Constants.States`. If I just right-click and select *Refactor - Move*, I  won't see `Constants.States` class among proposed destinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this. While static nested classes indeed seem not to be among the proposed classes, you can select the `Constants` class from the proposals and then simply add `.States` to the text field. Eclipse recognized the class (does not complain about the class not existing) and the refactoring worked as expected.

[image]

Comment: It works! I might have confused States and Statuses typing the name of the destination class.